# How to update ArrayAdapter in Fragment using AsyncTaskLoader?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm setting up a Fragment(TabLayout) and an ArrayAdapter for to display the list of words.
I want to update the Fragment after the data is completely fetched from source which is returned in onLoadFinished(). The AsyncTaskLoader is set in the MainActivity.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Word>> loader, List<Word> words) {

            if (words != null && !words.isEmpty()) {
        NounsFragment nounsFragment = new NounsFragment();
        nounsFragment.updateList(words);

        NumberFragment numberFragment = new NumberFragment();
        numberFragment.updateList(words);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "OnFinishedLoad status : " + words.size());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_words, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then I call the function in my fragment updateList() to update the fragent.

```
 public void updateList(List<Word> words) {

    // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
    //View loadingIndicator = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    //loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //TextView loadingTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_text_view);
    //loadingTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mAdapter.clear();

    if (words != null && !words.isEmpty()) {
        List<Word> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            Word word = words.get(i);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Current Word Category: " + word.getmCategory());
            if (word.getmCategory() != null) {
                if (word.getmCategory().contains("1"))
                    wordsList.add(word);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Item Added: " + word.getmEnglishTranslation());
            }
        }
        //words.add(new Word("Uhr", "Clock", 2));
        //words.add(new Word("Bleistift","Pencil", 1 ));
        mAdapter.addAll(wordsList);
    } else {

        // Set empty state text to display "No earthquakes found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_words);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_words, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I'm getting runtime error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.german, PID: 24298
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.german.WordAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.german.NounsFragment.updateList(NounsFragment.java:63)
                                                                            at com.example.android.german.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                            at com.example.android.german.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                            at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
                                                                            at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
                                                                            at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:144)
                                                                            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:265)
                                                                            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: where you have created mAdapter object?

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya Its a global variable in fragment class

Comment: please show me how you have initialize

Comment: private WordAdapter mAdapter;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....

mAdapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Word>());

...
}

Comment: first let me tell you adapter is not providing any clear(), if you have created clear() in your adapter class then please show me.

Comment: WordAdapter is extended to ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to understand 2 things before proceeding, the first async task will perform the operation in a background thread and to pass the data received from the background thread to the main thread using onPostExecute() and secondly, you need to update the UI **when** the data has been received successfully.

Now you need to follow simple steps
1. Create a listview/recyclerview to display data by setting up the adapters and stuff.
2. make an empty list of items like

```
List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
```

This step is important as you shouldn't recreate the list or re-assign the variable words again.
3. Execute the task in the background thread using AsyncTask and receive the data on the main thread using onPostExecute()
4. After receiving the data pass it to the MainActivity or the activity you want to pass it to MainActivity, it could be done using a method like setupUI() which returns the List<>.
5. clear the previous list to avoid repetition of the items and then simply add all the items to the existing list using list.addAll().
6. Call the notifyDataSetChanged() from there to update the UI

```
mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```